# External Stored procedure blocks when called from trigger

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sqlclr

I have a stored procedure calling an external function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFoo_CallApp]
    @Url [nvarchar](max),
    @Payload [int],
    @Type [nvarchar](max)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [Foo_HttpCaller].[StoredProcedures].[CallWebService]
```

Calling directly from SSMS works perfectly. The stored procedure finishes in almost no time.

However, when calling it from a trigger, it takes some time and throws an error message.

```
DECLARE @Id int

SELECT @Id = Id 
FROM FooBelege AS T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS T2 WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id)

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC [dbo].[spFoo_CallApp]
        @Url = N'https://...../trigger/',
        @Payload = 219095,
        @Type = N'VK'
```

Error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.spFoo_CallApp, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "spFoo_CallApp":
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> System.Net.WebException:
> at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
> at StoredProcedures.CallWebService(SqlString url, SqlInt32 payload, SqlString Type)

What is even more funny, it depends on the payload. Using the 219095
works only when calling the stored procedure directly but not from inside of the trigger. Using another Id works even from the trigger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Basically, don't do it. A database is not designed to operate that way, especially not from within a trigger. Triggers, if used at all, need to be fast and non-blocking. Anything else should be done from an application or service.

Comment: That said, it's telling you the error, the site is returning a 500, which is nothing to do with SQL Server, check your site logs. Hopefully the site you are calling doesn't call back into the same database!?

Comment: What do you imagine the value of `@id` would be if multiple rows exist in the `inserted` table?

Comment: Ignoring the fact of calling out to a web service from a trigger, I would suggest you add some debugging such as `print`ing out or logging the parameter values to a table to verify they are what you think they are. Aside, consider using appropriate data types. URLs for example do not exceed 8k in length; officially it can be up to 2k, but you probably know your URL is a lot smaller than that.

Comment: Trigger is executed on which command? `UPDATE` or `INSERT` or `DELETE` ?
Your SP probably causes the trigger to run again. You must use `@@NESTLEVEL` to prevent the trigger from being re-executed. In the first line of the trigger, use this code: `IF (@@NESTLEVEL = 1) BEGIN ......`